# R: Scraping with rvest - get title from href-data

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape player datails for FIFA 21 from https://www.futbin.com/21/players, but I have problems with some data.

Scraping the table works fine with this code

```
url2 <- "https://www.futbin.com/21/players?page=1&search=messi"
html <- read_html(url2)

html_table(html,header=FALSE)
```

But how do I get the nation, club and league of the player? With `tmp <- html %>% html_nodes('.players_club_nation')` I find the data, ...

```
> tmp
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <span class="players_club_nation" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                                                <a href="/21/players?page=1&amp;se ...
[2] <span class="players_club_nation" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                                                <a href="/21/players?page=1&amp;se ...
[3] <span class="players_club_nation" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                                                <a href="/21/players?page=1&amp;se ...
[4] <span class="players_club_nation" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                                                <a href="/21/players?page=1&amp;se ...
[5] <span class="players_club_nation" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                                                <a href="/21/players?page=1&amp;se ...
[6] <span class="players_club_nation" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                                                <a href="/21/players?page=1&amp;se ...
> tmp[[1]]
{html_node}
<span class="players_club_nation" style="display: inline-block;">
[1] <a href="/21/players?page=1&amp;search=messi&amp;club=241" data-original-title="FC Barcelona" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><img style="wi ...
[2] <a href="/21/players?page=1&amp;search=messi&amp;nation=52" data-original-title="Argentina" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><img style="widt ...
[3] <a href="/21/players?page=1&amp;search=messi&amp;league=53" data-original-title="LaLiga Santander" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><img styl ...
```

...but I am not able to extract the values from data-original-title. Is there a function in rvest or do I have to manipulate the string?

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply` and `html_attr` this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2

url2 <- "https://www.futbin.com/21/players?page=1&search=messi"
html <- read_html(url2)

tmp <- html %>% 
  html_nodes('.players_club_nation') 

tmp %>% 
  lapply(function(x) html_nodes(x, "a") %>% html_attr("data-original-title"))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "FC Barcelona"     "Argentina"        "LaLiga Santander"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "FC Barcelona"     "Argentina"        "LaLiga Santander"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "FC Barcelona"     "Argentina"        "LaLiga Santander"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "FC Barcelona"     "Argentina"        "LaLiga Santander"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "Portimonense SC"  "Brazil"           "Liga NOS (POR 1)"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "Crotone"     "Brazil"      "Serie A TIM"
```

Comment: Perfekt! The second html_nodes(x, "a") was my problem